# Apache POI XSSFTable.java:294 arrayindex out of bounds

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to edit an xls file through apache POI, but while calling workbook.write(fileOutpuStream), I am getting the following error :

```
ERROR [2018-01-16 20:33:50,817] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable.setCellReferences(XSSFTable.java:294)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable.getStartCellReference(XSSFTable.java:266)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable.updateHeaders(XSSFTable.java:347)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable.writeTo(XSSFTable.java:93)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable.commit(XSSFTable.java:104)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:414)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:419)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:419)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:242)
```

Some lines of my code are :

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream)
Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
/* iterate through rows and columns, write at the last column (fixed number) */
fileInputSream.close()
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close()
```

A similar code was working for me earlier, so I have no idea what is wrong with this. I'm literally stuck on this.

**EDIT:**

I got to part pointed by jontro.
It is indeed finding only the start reference of my sheet.

I have an excel like :

```
id | name   | result
1  | first  |  
2  | second |
```

I am iterating through the rows, and creating users in my system, if created successfully, I write true (false) in the result column. Since xlsx is created through google spreadsheets, I do not have an end row so if I find empty name, I break out of the row iterator. Then execute the part of my code below the comments, written above.

**EDIT 2:**

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(localFile);
try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is)) {
  Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = iterator.next();
    Data data = new Data(row.cellIterator());
    //do something with data
    data.getCell().setCellValue("processed");
  }
  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
  workbook.write(fileOut); //fails here
  fileOut.close();
} catch (Exception e) {//print
}



public class Data {
Data (Iterator<Cell> iterator) {
  Cell cell = iterator.next();
  this.var1 = cell.getStringCellValue();
  cell = iterator.next();
  this.var2 = cell.getStringValue();
  ....
  this.cell = iterator.next(); //this is for saying processed
}
```

I am starting to agree with Axel's comment that this has to do with google spreadsheet creation of Table objects. I have a similar code, where there is a different class Data, and that worked! I double verified everything and nothing was different.

Comment: try 
System.out.println(workbook.getNumberOfSheets()); before Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Comment: The problem is definitely with your data. `XSSFTable` is only involved if the workbook not only contains simple worksheets but has [Microsoft Office Excel table (previously known as an Excel list)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) in the sheets. So I suspect google spreadsheets does something while creating those `Table` objects what `apache poi` does not expect. So to help we would need the xlsx what was created through google spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the code in the trunk of [XSSFTable.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.java) we can see the following code

```
private void setCellReferences() {
    String ref = ctTable.getRef();
    if (ref != null) {
        String[] boundaries = ref.split(":", 2);
        String from = boundaries[0];
        String to = boundaries[1];
        startCellReference = new CellReference(from);
        endCellReference = new CellReference(to);
    }
}
```

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown on the following line `String to = boundaries[1];`

The cell reference is expected to be in the form `A1:B3` or similar. Since you do not post your loop it's hard to say exactly what is causing this error. Check that you are not creating incomplete cell ranges

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the issue. I was initially wondering, can break on iterator cause problems. After further testing I found it isn't. Still stuck at the same place. What worries me, is that this code worked a couple of months back.

Comment: Can you show the code? Try to reduce it as much as possible